# UIButton stopped responding during development

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uikit

I have a couple of buttons in a view. These were tested a few days ago and were working fine. Today for some reason they stopped working. The buttons are custom, with an image. They are connected to an action like:

```
- (IBAction)walkTurnByTurn:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked Turn By Turn Walk");
    CLLocationCoordinate2D destination = self.loadOficina.coordinate;
    MKPlacemark *endLocation = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destination addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *endingItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:endLocation];
    [endingItem setName:self.loadOficina.title];
    NSMutableDictionary *launchOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [launchOptions setObject:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking forKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey];

    [endingItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

I deleted the button and created it again, connected it to the action. It is enabled, user interaction enabled as well. It looks like it is just not responding to touches at all because it doesn't change color when clicked. 
Any ideas what might have happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably out of the bounds of its superview.  If the superview frame is 0,0,100,100 you can add the button as a subview that starts at, say, 200,200.  It will show up on the screen but it won't respond to events.  This is happening to a lot of people with iPhone 5 layouts.  They accidentally hardcode the window to 320x480.  The controls show up at y positions > 480 but they aren't interactive.